# VB How to extract attachments from a mime encoded text file

Tags: vb.net, mime

We use a 3rd party company for our procurement.  Some POs have supporting documents like Word, Excel...etc.  The company can provide us back the documents in a txt file containing the documents mime encoded.  Example below.

Looking for a VB solution to read this file and extract the document(s) to disk.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-------------------------------MIME_BOUNDARY_FOR_ATTACHMENTS
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <a4aad5dd-c89e-4c48-8c82-fac53938d751@sciquest.com>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="happy_path_reqs.png"

‰PNG
IHDR   È   ¥   2²  € IDATxÚì]`TUÖNOè`n¯ %4»»k_ËZé®ººÝ†kTºÒ{ï½ŠX‘
µ)&Ø¼BßÛGËY3pV£O!@â­È(i f’åˆ˜ðî]Û³©¬@¼B;ÿš„=´†kË Mî
µ)&Ø¼BßÛGËY3pV£O!@â­È(i f’åˆ˜ðî]Û³©¬@¼B;ÿš„=´†kË Mî
µ)&Ø¼BßÛGËY3pV£O!@â­È(i f’åˆ˜ðî]Û³©¬@¼B;ÿš„=´†kË Mî
µ)&Ø¼BßÛGËY3pV£O!@â­È(i f’åˆ˜ðî]Û³©¬@¼B;ÿš„=´†kË Mî
-------------------------------MIME_BOUNDARY_FOR_ATTACHMENTS--
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VB.NET, but you should be able to use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) to parse these MIME formatted files. I've been using it with a lot of success for quite a while now.

In C#, you would do something like this:

```
var message = MimeMessage.Load ("email.msg");

foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments) {
    using (var stream = File.Create (attachment.FileName))
        attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo (stream);
}
```

In VB.NET, it would probably be something like this:

```
Dim message As MimeMessage.Load ("email.msg")

For Each attachment As MimePart In message.Attachments
    Dim stream As File.Create (attachment.FileName)
    attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo (stream)
    stream.Dispose ()
Next
```